# In Julia, how to un-`dev` a package?

Tags: package, julia

I previously used Pkg's `dev` command to clone a package into my `.julia/dev` folder. How can I undo that operation so that Julia forgets that I have a local version tagged for development?

Comment: I believe it's `free MyPackage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dev` can be undone by `free`.

Note that in the Julia package manager you can use `help` command:

```
(@v1.8) pkg> help dev
(...)
  Make a package available for development. If pkg is an existing local path, that path will be recorded in the manifest and used.
(...)
  This operation is undone by free.
(...)

(@v1.8) pkg> help free
  free pkg[=uuid] ...
  free [--all]

  Free pinned packages, which allows it to be upgraded or downgraded again. If the package is checked out (see help develop) then
  this command makes the package no longer being checked out.
```